# How do I specify a line of text in a text file for a batch file

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I am wondering if I can tell the computer to do a command on a text file with a batch file, however I would like to specify which line to modify.

I do not have any code for this yet and I would be grateful if you could give a detailed explanation.

When and if I get this command I am planing to use it to delete or write on that exact line and not overwrite another.

Comment: batch files on their own are pretty horrible for text operations. Are you averse to using stuff like sed or awk, or powershell?

Comment: i dont know what 'sed,awk or powershell' is but if you are refering to programing languages then no.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this through the Windows command prompt is more fun than it is practical, but it is possible. You can use `for /f` to go through a file one line at a time, but I know of no trivial way to keep track of the current line. The following code uses a call to a subroutine to count the lines manually. The batch file is to be called using the filename, line number to replace and the replacing string.

```
@echo off
set filename=%1
set targetline=%2
set message=%3
set n=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%i in (%filename%) do call :write %%i
exit /b 0

:write
set /a n+=1
if %n%==%targetline% (echo %message%) else echo %*
exit /b 0
```

Sample output of `replace.bat somelines.txt 3 "Hello, world!"`:

```
first line
second line
"Hello, world!"
fourth line
```

Comment: Cool thanx, so by using for /f i can set the line to use.

Answer (score 0):

[Sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) will allow you to perform line-oriented operations on text files:

> Sed (streams editor) isn't really a true text editor or text
>   processor. Instead, it is used to filter text, i.e., it takes text
>   input and performs some operation (or set of operations) on it and
>   outputs the modified text. Sed is typically used for extracting part
>   of a file using pattern matching or substituting multiple occurances
>   of a string within a file.

Comment: how do i use sed?

Comment: That all depends on what you're doing. I recommend you find a good tutorial and a sturdy reference, since sed is one of the largest text manipulation tools in use, and having even a passing knowledge of it is useful.

Comment: what do you suggest i seach into google to get a good reference on this?

Comment: i have never heard of it :(

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=sed+tutorial

Comment: thanks but i can only use a batch file for this :( it is a assignment for high school.